# Combine 2 SQL queries into 1 from same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single MySQL table that needs querying twice to produce produce results in this format:

```
+------------+----------+-------------------+
|  Supplier  | Requests | Requests_Approved |
+------------+----------+-------------------+
| Supplier 1 |       50 |                45 |
| Supplier 2 |       75 |                63 |
| Supplier 3 |       48 |                32 |
| Supplier 4 |      104 |                87 |
+------------+----------+-------------------+
```

So far, I have tried the following:

```
SELECT Supplier, COUNT(*) AS Requests, COUNT(*) AS Requests_Approved
FROM pricematch
WHERE Date_Received >=  '2015-01-01'
AND Date_Received <=  '2015-12-31'
AND PM_Level =  'Escalation'
GROUP BY Supplier
UNION 
SELECT Supplier, COUNT(*) AS Requests, COUNT(*) AS Approved
FROM pricematch
WHERE Date_Time_Received >=  '2015-01-01'
AND Date_Time_Received <=  '2015-12-31'
AND PM_Level =  'Escalation'
AND Matched =  'Yes'
GROUP BY Supplier
ORDER BY Requests DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Which produces the following results table, with the same results in both number columns:

```
+------------+----------+-------------------+
|  Supplier  | Requests | Requests_Approved |
+------------+----------+-------------------+
| Supplier 1 |       50 |                50 |
| Supplier 2 |       75 |                75 |
| Supplier 3 |       48 |                48 |
| Supplier 4 |      104 |               104 |
+------------+----------+-------------------+
```

I have reviewed many similar questions/answers here and have tried alternatives using LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN, but the query always fails.

Comment: And what is the confusion?  You are using `COUNT(*)` to calculate both, so I would be really, really surprised if the values were not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Conditional Aggregate`

```
SELECT Supplier,
       Count(*)   AS Requests,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN Matched = 'Yes' THEN 1
             END) AS Approved
FROM   pm
WHERE  Date_Received >= '2015-01-01'
       AND Date_Received <= '2015-12-31'
       AND PM_Level = 'Escalation'
GROUP  BY Supplier
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the quick response. Will mark as the correct answer (as first replied) when possible in 8 minutes :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am going to speculate that `pm` is the same as `pricematch` and you really want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Supplier, COUNT(*) AS Requests,
       SUM(Matched =  'Yes') AS Approved
FROM pricematch pm
WHERE Date_Time_Received >=  '2015-01-01' AND
      Date_Time_Received <=  '2015-12-31' AND
      PM_Level =  'Escalation' 
GROUP BY Supplier
ORDER BY Requests DESC 
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: Yes indeed - question updated with correct table name. Thanks for the quick response! :-)